# What is significance of Athi Rudra Mahayagnam?

Tags: vedas, shiva, yajna, rudram

> There are [five methods](http://www.skandagurunatha.org/works/stothras/sri-rudram.pdf) of chanting the [Rudram](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11792/3500) viz.
>
> 1. **Ordinary method** (aka 1 Rudram) = where first Namakam (all 11 anuväkas)  are read followed by the Chamakam.
> 2. **Rudra ekadasini**= where after chanting Rudram, the first anuväka of  Chamakam is chanted, again after chanting Rudram the second anuväka of 
>      Chamakam is chanted and so on till the eleventh chanting of Rudram 
>      followed by eleventh anuväka of Chamakam.
> 3. Eleven such Rudra ekadasinis makes one **Laghu Rudram**.
> 4. Eleven such Laghu Rudrams makes one **Maha Rudram.**
> 5. Eleven such Maha Rudrams make one **Athi Rudram**.

I would like to know the significance of **AthiRudra MahaYagnam**.
with respect to **Physical, Spiritual and Scientific level**.
Any one who know please shed some light .
Thanks

Comment: One can get immortality by reciting Sri Rudram. It is confirmed in two Upanishads: Kaivalya Upanishad and Jabala Upanishad...

Comment: @tezz Thanks, Want to know more based on the 3 levels mentioned above

Comment: @TheDestroyer - Nice explanation in edit.