# In which verse of Shukla YajurVeda is Om Namah Shivaya mantra present?

Tags: vedas, shiva, yajur-veda, shukla-yajurveda

I know that the 'Om Namah Shivaya' mantra is present in Krishna YajurVeda, but i have been led to believe that it's also present in the Shukla YajurVeda. Please share the location the verse.

Comment: Related [Which verse of Sri Rudram of Yajurveda has the word “Shiva”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10818/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer that post is krishna Yajurveda he is asking shukla

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Changed it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

In the famous rudra [ashtadhyAyi](https://archive.org/details/HindiBook--rudrashtadhyayi.pdf) of MAdhyandina samhita. There is this mantra in the fifth chapter. It is taken from the moola samhita.

Comment: Thank you very much. After much asking around d you gave the answer. I have a request. Could you please share a website when I can read about rudra ashtadhyAyi of MAdhyandina samhita. I shall paste this information in the wikipedia also. If you provide good citation (i.e. website) where the samhita is given. Many thanks again.

Comment: @ShivSahilGuleri i have updated the answer with the link

Comment: @ShivSahil  you must tick this answer. It will help other readers also.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi thank you very much. Is this mantra available in any other Veda. If yes could you please share them.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi In the following page (https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/अष्टाध्यायी) It's mentioned that it's a linguistic text. But i am unable to find it;s written that it's a part of the MAdhyandina samhita. Please clarity!

Comment: @ShivSahilGuleri https://hi.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/रुद्राष्टाध्यायी