# Where is Sri Rudram Hymn present in the Vedas? I know it's in Krishna YajurVeda. Is it present In Shukula YajurVeda also?

Tags: vedas, yajur-veda, shukla-yajurveda

Here is a link where i have read that it's present in Adhyaya 16 of Vajasena Samhita: [Which verse of Sri Rudram of Yajurveda has the word "Shiva"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10818/which-verse-of-sri-rudram-of-yajurveda-has-the-word-shiva)

If yes please share the link where this samhita

Comment: You also answered the question on where is Sri Rudram in Shukla Yajurveda also. Do you want only the link?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma It would be great if you can share the link . I am unable to find one.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in my previous post, Rudram is present in the shukla yajurveda which is part of Rudra ashtadhyaayi which is a collection of some mantras of shukla yajurveda vajasaneyi samhita.

The fifth chapter of [Rudra ashtadhyayi](https://archive.org/stream/HindiBook--rudrashtadhyayi.pdf/HindiBook--rudrashtadhyayi#page/n61/mode/2up) is the rudram (as in Krishna yajurveda) and the eighth chapter of Rudra-ashtadhyaayi is the chamakam (as in KY).

The whole of the 8 chapters are chanted generally for the rudrabhishekam.

Some of the audios/videos for the chanting are [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPlEZDKxhcE) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTmQzYeC35I).

Apart from that it is also in the sAma veda,

rUdraM is very celebrated hymn of all vedas.Each veda and its shAkhA have its own rUdraM .Following is text of [sAmaveda rUdraM](https://animeshnagarblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/19/samaveda-rudram/) according to kauThuma shAkhA with a initial outline. Before reciting it sAmavedIya mAhAnyAsaM , sAmavedIya shadanga nyAsaM and dashAkshara nyAsaM are performed , than meditation on rUdra is done.Then the reciter perform vinIyogaMs of all sAma mantras used.

sAmaveda rUdraM according to kauThuma shAkhA consists of following seven parts .

1) paviThra varaga

It consists of 11 samayonIs and there respective sAmagAnas.( SAmaveda samhitA mantras no ) 627, 27,600, 147, 318, 27, 463, 469 , 440, 441 and 495.
This group of sAmas blesses the reciter with purity hence are called paviThras.

2) arishTa varga

It consists of 8 samayonIs, and there respective sAmagAnas.( SAmaveda samhitA mantras no ) 192, 196,318,332,333,572, 582 and 437.

3) vinAyaka samhitA

From the name it is clear that these group of sAmas are dedicated to lord vinAyaka.
It consists of 4 samayonIs, and there respective sAmagAnas.( SAmaveda samhitA mantras no ) 315,316,167 and 417

4) skanda samhitA

These mantras are dedicated to kumar dhUrta . It consists of 4 samayonIs, and there respective sAmagAnas.( SAmaveda samhitA mantras no ) 246,269,533 and 565.

5) vishnU samhitA

Thse sAmas are dedicated to lord mahAvishnU.It consits of vaishnava SAmas and purUsha suktaM of sAmaveda. It consists of 8 samayonIs, and there respective sAmagAnas.( SAmaveda samhitA mantras no ) 222,609,524,617,618,619,620 and 621.

6) rUdra samhitA

These mantras are dedicated to lord rUdra. It consists of 6 samayonIs and there respective sAmagAnas.( SAmaveda samhitA mantras no )69,115,67 and three mantras from stobha pada pAtha.

7) shAntI sAmas

It consists of pacifying sAma mantras including the famous vAmadevya sAma. It consists of 4 samayonIs and there respective sAmagAnas.( SAmaveda samhitA mantras no ) 616,682,683 and 684 .

Comment: Vinayaka samhita- lord shiva's son vinayaka?